# Can we reopen this question please? [Now re-CLOSED]

Tags: discussion, question-closure, specific-question

**Edit note 2:**

The patient and long-suffering OP has now re-asked aspects of this question in three separate posts. So, there's now probably no harm in leaving this one closed.

---

This useful question on parts of speech got closed:

[Are these parts of speech correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/357709/are-these-parts-of-speech-correct)

Arguably, it was a bit difficult to read in the original version. It has since been reformatted by the original poster and the question more clearly set out. I think it is precisely the kind of question we should have on a site for linguists and serious language enthusiasts. Can we reopen it please?

Comment: It's open again.

Comment: Thanks @DanBron

Comment: Are you going to reformulate your answer to accord with the edited question? Which in my view is poorly reformulated because it is now asking multiple questions in one question post. I think the material is worthy of the site and I didn't have a problem with it, other than the readability factor to which I commented, in its original conception.

Comment: Apart from the issue of whether such a question should be welcomed here, why do you keep insisting on reopening too broad a question? One question per post is the guideline of Stack Exchange and ELU is a Stack Exchange site. Why can't we ask the OP to narrow it down to one particular issue? I don't think it is that difficult as I commented to the main board question, The one question policy is black and white and there is strong argument to support that. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post. Experienced users should not encourage this type of Qs.

Comment: @DanBron I think reopening the question leaves a pretty bad example. The question can be split into three Qs and I strongly believe it should be.

Comment: @Rathony I've initiated the re-closing of the question.

Comment: @curiousdannii I can't vote to close it again. What is happening on ELU?

Comment: @Rathony You can never vote to close it twice if your first vote was effective. Hopefully enough other people will see it. Only need four more :)

Comment: @curiousdannii It was not that I didn't know the rule. I know I can't vote to close it again. The OP seems to have realized what's wrong with that question and promised to ask two questions later. Let's see how it goes. **More important issue**: Why couldn't we have waited until the post was edited before answering the question?

Comment: @Rathony the post was answered before the three questions were formulated the way they are now. It was more of a general question about parts of speech, not three separate ones. A respected community user felt it was a question worth answering, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @curiousdannii I re-edited the tags, because we have an existing one for discussing reopening closed questions. The other one Rathony created is at best helpful to discuss the merit of reopen votes, which this question is not about.

Comment: @Rathony actually I did count. The question I took from it was about why adding parts of speech to every word is a bad idea. Sure there were some more question marks, but that was what I read in there. That's not very specific, but not necessarily too broad. Some people see it as such, some don't. That's why I have no problem at all with someone answering it.

Comment: @Rathony A small duo of you feel that. Unlike the 8 people who upvoted the answer  and the many people who very fast voted to reopen the question. We get too few good grammar and syntax questions on here. We need to cherish the ones we have. You are interpreting the guidelines too narrowly. You also claim the answer is oo long. But as has already been explained, it looks long because of the way it has been formatted - done that way to make it clear. You are not repecting the democratic procedure for reopening and closing questions.

Comment: @Rathony there are also seven up votes on the question. Also the meta post you cite does not address the closeness of the sentences ending in question marks. There can be a post which has a dozen question marks yet only asks really one question. The interpretation if a question is indeed several questions or a single question that is too broad is up to the voting users. They voted, it's now open.

Comment: I realized the same process is applied to "leave open" votes. I will move on. Deleted all my comments I posted today.

Comment: @Rathony Cheers old bean. Looking forward to reading some more of your posts! :-)

Comment: @Araucaria The question is re-closed. I think it has more to do with the OP's failure in keeping the promise of asking two other different questions by editing it. Now, it seems to be 16:5. Let's move on. Don't answer too broad a question. I will make sure I vote to delete the question unless it is edited as the question is off-topic. An answer to off-topic question is useless when the question is deleted.

Comment: @Helmar In case you didn't do a reopen vote, if you think the question should be open, it needs five more :)

Comment: @Araucaria I did in the first round

Comment: @Helmar I hope you keep what I said in the chat room in your mind. Stack Exchange has clear guidelines. It is different from other discussion forums.

Comment: @Helmar Thanks for that. I'll get on the reopen mission tomorow :)

Comment: @Rathony don't worry, I won't vote again unless there is an edit. However I will apply my understanding of those guidelines when voting, not yours. The world isn't always black and white.

Comment: @Helmar Glad to know that. I am very thankful that we had some time to discuss some issues.

Comment: @Araucaria Helmar voted to leave "closed" in the reopen queue and voted to reopen it when he saw your Meta post. I wanted to mention it before, but...

Comment: My very greatest respect for @Helmar then. He seems to be a very positive and useful member of the site. Thanks for confirming that. I wish we had more members like Helmar!

Comment: @Rathony See above.

Comment: Voted to reopen.

Comment: @JOSH Why? Defend that it is not too broad.

Comment: @Rathony I am sick. I have a family. I have a job. I have responsibilities. I am sorry that these prevented me from carrying out the activities you wanted according to a quicker timeline. Consider how this ugly process has jerked me around. I've never had a question closed twice! And almost reopened yet again. But in the final analysis, I think I've been shockingly nice. I get that ESE has its rules. But sometimes we just want some help with something we think of as a single issue or task. It's the nature of things. Upvoters saw things differently from you and some others.

Comment: @Rathony P.S. I've been using stackoverflow since near the beginning and have 25k points there—I'm not entirely ignorant of how SE works. Yet still I made this awful too-broad-question mistake on ESE. Have a smidgen of patience, please.

Comment: We get too many questions like this http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358347/what-is-the-word-for-when-someone-is-overly-nice-and-actually-isnt-nice-at-all and we have problems with a real question with serious content ?

Comment: @ab2 There was no problem with the question, only that it had enough content for three questions. That's what "too broad" means!

Comment: @curiousdannii The question was as broad as a stick of spaghetti.

Comment: Keeping people from asking questions you dislike -- Don't you people have anything better to do than discuss the philosophy of censorship?

Comment: @Rathony - "What is happening on ELU?" Now that's a question I'd like to see. My take is that there's but a single moderator that has taken point (or rather, been left with the job), one that has an agenda that I don't personally agree with but who IMO has SE's best interests at heart, so I cannot fault them for it. At least [they've remembered to stop and smell the roses](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359359/within-or-inside/359360#359360) once in a while. When is the next election? (not that I think anyone should be ousted. We just need more on the ~3rd most popular site of SE)